# Twitter Sentiment Analysis CSV io.unsupportedOperation error

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I am writting a program in Python, that is using Twitter's API and It is searching twitter for a list of tweets about any topic we want, then analyze each tweet to see how positive or negative it's emotion is. 
In the beginning I used for loop to print out the tweets in the cmd. Initial code of loop in the program

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
public_tweets = api.search("Estonia")
for tweet in public_tweets:
print(tweet.text.encode("utf-8"))
analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
print(analysis.sentiment)
```

Now I wanted to make write directly into a text file using csv, but an error occurs
Code:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
public_tweets = api.search("Estonia")
with  open("sentiment.txt") as scoreFile:
scoreFileWriter = csv.writer(scoreFile)
for tweet in public_tweets:
text = tweet.text
analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
sentiment = analysis.sentiment.polarity
scoreFileWriter.writerow([text, sentiment])
```

Error

```
C:\Users\ArturErik\Desktop>python sentiment.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment.py", line 23, in <module>
    scoreFileWriter.writerow([text, sentiment])
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

I am new to Python and I cannot fix the bug.

Comment: There are many reasons why writing to a file can fail. Does the file exist? Does Python have write access to the file? From the looks of the error, it doesn't seem as though the file was writable. In the future, please include steps you've taken to resolve the problem. In this case, have you tried making the file writable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
 open("sentiment.txt",'w')
```